# Using Spring & JPA, getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

So I've been trying to get this application to work utilising Spring 4, Spring Boot 1.4, and Hibernate 5 (verified by checking maven dependencies in Maven, but for whatever reason, it will not acknowledge my settings for where to look for the Entity classes in a particular package, instead looking in a totally different package that I can't find where it's been specified. Steps such as using javax.persistence pacakge instead of org.hibernate have been fruitless. Using SessionFactory instead of EntityManager also produced the same error. No persistence.xml is used (or indeed any xml, as using Spring 3, I wanted a completely Java based configuration, and from research this should be possible?

Without further ado, here's the current code.

The POM file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.40</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inventory")
public class InventoryDBModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productID;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "store_id")
    private int storeID;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "reported_on")
    private String reportedOn; //Convert to Date

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private String updatedAt; //Convert to Date

    public int getProductID() {
        return productID;
    }

    public int getStoreID() {
        return storeID;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getReportedOn() {
        return reportedOn;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setProductID(final int productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public void setStoreID(final int storeID) {
        this.storeID = storeID;
    }

    public void setQuantity(final int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setReportedOn(final String reportedOn) {
        this.reportedOn = reportedOn;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(final String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
}
```

The DAO interface:

```
public interface InventoryDAO {
    public void createOne(LCBOInventory lcboInventory);

    public void createMany(List<? extends LCBOInventory> lcboInventorysItems);

    public void delete(int productID, int styleID);

    public List<LCBOInventory> getByProduct(int productID);

    public LCBOInventory getByProductAndStore(int productID, int storeID);

    public List<LCBOInventory> getByStore(int storeID);

    public List<LCBOInventory> list();

    public void updateOne(LCBOInventory lcboInventory);

    public void updateMany(List<LCBOInventory> lcboInventoryItems); 
}
```

The DAO Implementation class:

```
public class InventoryDAOImpl implements InventoryDAO {

    static final String SELECT_INVENTORY = "SELECT i FROM inventory ";
    static final String PRODUCTID = "productID";
    static final String STOREID = "storeID";

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    public InventoryDAOImpl() {
         //basic constructor
    }

    public InventoryDAOImpl(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void createOne(final LCBOInventory newLCBOInventoryItem) {
        LCBOInventory lcboInventoryObject = new LCBOInventory();

        lcboInventoryObject.setProductID(newLCBOInventoryItem.getProductID());
        lcboInventoryObject.setQuantity(newLCBOInventoryItem.getQuantity());
        lcboInventoryObject.setReportedOn(newLCBOInventoryItem.getReportedOn());
        lcboInventoryObject.setStoreID(newLCBOInventoryItem.getStoreID());
        lcboInventoryObject.setUpdatedAt(newLCBOInventoryItem.getUpdatedAt());

        em.persist(lcboInventoryObject);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void createMany(final List<? extends LCBOInventory> lcboInventorysItems) {       
        lcboInventorysItems.stream().forEach((currentInventoryItem) -> {
            LCBOInventory lcboInventoryObject = new LCBOInventory();

            lcboInventoryObject.setProductID(currentInventoryItem.getProductID());
            lcboInventoryObject.setQuantity(currentInventoryItem.getQuantity());
            lcboInventoryObject.setReportedOn(currentInventoryItem.getReportedOn());
            lcboInventoryObject.setStoreID(currentInventoryItem.getStoreID());
            lcboInventoryObject.setUpdatedAt(currentInventoryItem.getUpdatedAt());

            em.persist(lcboInventoryObject);
        }); 
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(final int productID, final int styleID) {
        Query loadSpecificProductStoreCombo = em.createQuery("DELETE i FROM inventory i WHERE i.productID = :productID AND i.storeID = :storeID");

        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.setParameter("productID", productID);
        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.setParameter("storeID", styleID);

        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public List<LCBOInventory> getByProduct(final int productID) {
        TypedQuery<LCBOInventory> loadInventoryByProduct = em.createQuery(SELECT_INVENTORY + "WHERE i.productID = :productID " +
                                                                            "AND i.storeID = :storeID", LCBOInventory.class);

        loadInventoryByProduct.setParameter("productID", productID);

        return loadInventoryByProduct.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public LCBOInventory getByProductAndStore(final int productID, final int storeID) {
        TypedQuery<LCBOInventory> loadSpecificProductStoreCombo = em.createQuery(SELECT_INVENTORY + "WHERE i.productID = :productID " +
                                                                                    "AND i.storeID = :storeID", LCBOInventory.class);

        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.setParameter("productID", productID);
        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.setParameter("storeID", storeID);

        return loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public List<LCBOInventory> getByStore(final int storeID) {
        TypedQuery<LCBOInventory> loadInventoryByStore = em.createQuery(SELECT_INVENTORY + "WHERE i.productID = :productID " +
                                                                            "AND i.storeID = :storeID", LCBOInventory.class);

        loadInventoryByStore.setParameter("storeID", storeID);

        return loadInventoryByStore.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<LCBOInventory> list() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM product i", LCBOInventory.class).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateOne(final LCBOInventory newLCBOInventoryItem) {
        TypedQuery<LCBOInventory> loadSpecificProductStoreCombo = em.createQuery(SELECT_INVENTORY + "WHERE i.productID = :productID " +
                                                                                    "AND i.storeID = :storeID", LCBOInventory.class);

        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.setParameter("productID", newLCBOInventoryItem.getProductID());
        loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.setParameter("storeID", newLCBOInventoryItem.getStoreID());

        LCBOInventory oldLCBOInventoryItem = loadSpecificProductStoreCombo.getSingleResult();

        oldLCBOInventoryItem.setProductID(newLCBOInventoryItem.getProductID());
        oldLCBOInventoryItem.setQuantity(newLCBOInventoryItem.getQuantity());
        oldLCBOInventoryItem.setReportedOn(newLCBOInventoryItem.getReportedOn());
        oldLCBOInventoryItem.setStoreID(newLCBOInventoryItem.getStoreID());
        oldLCBOInventoryItem.setUpdatedAt(newLCBOInventoryItem.getUpdatedAt());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMany(List<LCBOInventory> lcboInventoryItems) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

The Database configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.sample.hibernate.model")
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private LCBOInventoryTrackerProperties properties;

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class); 
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.sample.hibernate.model"}); 
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getDb().getDriver());
        dataSource.setUrl(properties.getDb().getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.getDb().getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getDb().getPassword());

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateConfigProperties = new Properties();

        hibernateConfigProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        hibernateConfigProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateConfigProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);
        hibernateConfigProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateConfigProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);

        return hibernateConfigProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException{
       JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(this.entityManagerFactory());

       return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
       return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    //DAO Autowires

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "inventoryDAO")
    public InventoryDAO getInventoryDAO(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new InventoryDAOImpl(entityManager);
    }
```

And last but not least, the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.sample.lcbo.domain.LCBOInventory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sample.lcbo.dao.InventoryDAOImpl.lambda$0(InventoryDAOImpl.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.sample.lcbo.dao.InventoryDAOImpl.createMany(InventoryDAOImpl.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.createMany(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sample.lcbo.writer.LCBOInventoryWriter.write(LCBOInventoryWriter.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:216) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:233) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:125) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:119) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sample.lcbo.config.LCBOBatchConfig.main(LCBOBatchConfig.java:69) [classes/:na]
```

Any help on this, I'd greatly appreciate. While I tried my best to be as through as possible, if there's any questions, please ask away and I'll attempt to provide.

Comment: well looks like you have mixed up some configs from a hibernate + spring project and some from a spring data project. Please read this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) carefully , and don't implement the DAO layer.  Also could you post the whole stacktrace and point to what actually you want to achieve....?

Comment: @AntJavaDev OH I'm not surprised that it looks like a collection of various items squished together into a patchwork quilt. Trying to find a quality tutorial was not easy, so had to take pieces from various sources. I'll give that tutorial another try, and have included a stacktrace for review. As for what to achieve, just be able to perform database operations using hibernate with Spring Batch. That's the general gist of what this project was started for.

Comment: The entity class in your question is named `InventoryDBModel`, whereas the type you are trying to persist is named `LCBOInventory`. Are you sure you have posted the correct code? Can you review the code (or your application) and post correct code (or correct your application)?

Comment: First of all the entity you posted`InventoryDBModel` is not referred in your code. Secondly . from your stacktrace , its quite clear that *Unknown entity : com.sample.lcbo.domain.LCBOInventory* , as you are passing to your entityManager this package to scan `com.sample.hibernate.model` ... ?

Comment: So found the reason for this looks to be a poor implementation of multiple tutorials. A complete refactor of the code to use straight Spring JPA and nothing of the old code looks to have resolved the issue. Apologies for the confusion, the joys of learning new tech.

Answer (score 2):

Importantly, `persistence.xml` free approach is possible since Spring 3.1. See docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-jpa-without-xml).

Also, you should to know that Spring Boot 1.4 requires Spring Framework 4.3. See [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#spring-framework-43) of it.

Did you see the official Spring guide [Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)?

**UPDATE #1**

You are trying to use entity `com.sample.lcbo.domain.LCBOInventory` (see exception details), but you set `com.sample.hibernate.model` into `EntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've verified that the application has Spring core 4.3.4, Spring boot 1.4.2, and Hibernite 5.0.11 listed as jar's under Maven Dependencies in Eclipse.

I've also checked the Spring Guides that were linked. It didn't look like I was missing anything of note, or at least anything that would cause this error to occur.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The item it's referring too isn't a domain, but just a class that defines an inventory object. The Entity classes are located in "com.sample.hibernate.model", but for whatever reason the program wants to go to com.sample.lcbo.domain, which isn't indicated anywhere for it to scan. Hence the confusion

Comment: There is no confusion because you use 'persist' and 'select query' of EntityManager with LCBOInventory class and that's why Hibernate considers this class to be the entity class. InventoryDBModel should be used in the DAO instead of LCBOInventory.

Comment: interesting. I figured the Entity annotation and setPackages would be how it's determined.